# How to check values of child elements of specific parent element?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have some xml files in which there might be some elements named `list`, which has an attribute `list-type` with 3 possible values as **ordered, bullet** and **simple**.
Now

1) for `list-type="ordered"`, every element `list-item` must be followed by element `label` and the value of `label` **must not** start with **&#x**

2) for `list-type="bullet"`, every element `list-item` must be followed by element `label` and the value of `label` **must** start with **&#x**

3) for `list-type="simple"`, every element `list-item` **must not** be followed by element `label` (simple list does not have label's)

I'm trying to check if there are any `list-item`'s in the file that does not follow the above rules based on its immediate parent element `list`

I've tried

```
string path=@"C:\temp\list.xml";
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(path,LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
var simplelists=doc.Descendants("list").Where(x=>x.Attribute("list-type").Value=="simple");
if (simplelists!=null)
{
    foreach (var list in simplelists)
    {
        var x=list.Descendants("list-item").Where(a=>a.Elements("label").Any()).Select(a=>((IXmlLineInfo)a).LineNumber);
        if (x!=null)
        {
            foreach (var element in x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Check line: "+element+", <label> not supported in SIMPLE list");
            }

        }
    }
}

var orderedlists=doc.Descendants("list").Where(x=>x.Attribute("list-type").Value=="ordered");
if (orderedlists!=null)
{
    foreach (var list in orderedlists)
    {
        var x=list.Descendants("list-item").Where(a=>!a.Elements("label").Any() || a.Element("label").Value.StartsWith(@"&#x")).Select(a=>((IXmlLineInfo)a).LineNumber);
        if (x!=null)
        {
            foreach (var element in x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Check line: "+element+", <label> is either missing or has unsuppoted value for list-item (ORDERED list)");
            }

        }
    }
}

var bulletlists=doc.Descendants("list").Where(x=>x.Attribute("list-type").Value=="bullet");
if (bulletlists!=null)
{
    foreach (var list in bulletlists)
    {
        var x=list.Descendants("list-item").Where(a=>!a.Elements("label").Any() || !a.Element("label").Value.EndsWith(@"&#x")).Select(a=>((IXmlLineInfo)a).LineNumber);
        if (x!=null)
        {
            foreach (var element in x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Check line: "+element+", <label> is either missing or has unsuppoted value for list-item (BULLET list)");
            }

        }
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

But it is not doing what I intended, here is a [sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cqdw1kqldxz465d/list.xml?dl=0)

The desired output of the sample file is

```
Check line: 6, <label> is either missing or has unsuppoted value for list-item (ORDERED list)
Check line: 13, <label> not supported in SIMPLE list
Check line: 23, <label> is either missing or has unsuppoted value for list-item (ORDERED list)
```

I'm getting [image: this output]

Can anyone help me with this?

Note: There could be nested `list` elements inside another `list` element with same or different `list-type` values.

Comment: If lists can be nested then use `Elements` to get their list items instead of `Descendants`.

Comment: @juharr but the problem with that is I have to give the full tree of elements till `list` and that will vary..the sample file is just a short example, there could be other elements in the file which might contain elements `list` as well

Comment: Are you saying that list items can be nested in some other node that isn't a list, like `<list><somethingelse><list-item></list-item></somethingelse></list>`?  Because I'm only talking about the relationship between a list and it's list items.  You'd still use `Descendants` to get all of the lists.

Comment: @juharr no, have you checked the sample file? also the desired output and the output I'm getting

Comment: Yes and the reason you get all that extra output for the simple list is because you use `Descendants` instead of `Elements` when getting the list items.  You likely have another issue with the bullet one.

Comment: The Bullet issue is that you use `EndsWith` instead of `StartsWith`.

Comment: @juharr yes fixed that, what about the rest of the problem? can you show some code please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have 2 issues.  First you're pulling all the Descendant list items for each list, which will include the list items for nested lists.  The second issue is that the `"&#x####;"` in xml indicates an encoded character, so something like `"&#x2022;"` is replaced by the character it represents `"•"` (the bullet character).  So you need to determine which exact characters or some range that are invalid for ordered lists and required for bullets because any character can be encoded that way.  Here's code that will give your desired results and simplifies a lot of the duplication in your current code.

It should be noted that those characters do not have to be encoded.  You can replace the encoding with the actual unicode character in the xml.  The only reason they would need to be encoded is if the file itself needed to be saved in an encoding that doesn't support unicode characters.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
char[] invalidOrderedCharacter = new[] {'\u2022', '\u25CB' };
char[] requiredBulletCharacters = new[] {'\u2022'};
foreach (var list in doc.Descendants("list"))
{
    var listType = list.Attribute("list-type")?.Value;
    foreach (var item in list.Elements("list-item"))
    {
        var lineNumber = ((IXmlLineInfo) item).LineNumber;
        var label = item.Element("label")?.Value;
        switch (listType)
        {
            case "simple":
                if (label != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "Check line: " + lineNumber + 
                        ", <label> not supported in SIMPLE list");
                }
                break;
            case "ordered":
                if (label == null || invalidOrderedCharacter.Contains(label[0]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "Check line: " + lineNumber + 
                        ", <label> is either missing or has unsupported value for list-item (ORDERED list)");
                }
                break;
            case "bullet":
                if (label == null || !requiredBulletCharacters.Contains(label[0]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "Check line: " + lineNumber + 
                        ", <label> is either missing or has unsupported value for list-item (BULLET list)");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't work properly, have you run the code yourself?

Comment: The other issue is that `&#x` indicates that you're dealing with an encoded character, so the actual value is not those 3 characters, but something like "&#x2022;" is replaced by the character it represents "•" a really bold dot.  So you'll need to define the actual characters you want to check for since you can encode any character that way.

Comment: how do I write `var listType = list.Attribute("list-type")?.Value;` and `var label = item.Element("label")?.Value;` in older .net (like .net 4.5)? Thanks

Comment: `var listType = list.Attribute("list-type) == null ? null : list.Attribute("list-type").Value;`  or you could remove the `?.Value` and then change the location it's used after the null check like `swithc(listType.Value)` and `label.Value[0]`.